# Why the console.log is showing the values are undefined?

Tags: jquery

Hello I am just creating a button that after clicking it, the background color should change. But why its showing undefined.
Here is my code-

```
 var colors = ["#FA8072","#A0F12C"];
 var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random *( colors.length));

$(function(){

    function generateColor(){

        $('body').attr('style','background-color:'+colors[randomColor]); 

    }

    $('#generate').on('click',function(){

        generateColor();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn’t contain `console.log`.

Comment: `$('body').attr('style','background-color:'+colors[randomColor]);` should be `$('body').css('background-color', colors[randomColor]);`. Also, it's `Math.random()`, not `Math.random`

Comment: I know that when i click the button, it sets the attribute of style of background-color with undefined

Comment: `Math.random` is a function. Using the `*` operator on a function is not really useful. You probably want to call the function with `()` and use * on the result instead.

Comment: Thank you @Paulpro bro its a dangerous mistake

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var colors = ["#FA8072","#A0F12C"];


$(function(){

    function generateColor(){
        // You always have to create a new random number, once the button is clicked
        var randomColor = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length));
        $('body').css('background-color',colors[randomColor]);  

    }

    $('#generate').on('click',function(){

        generateColor();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets with [Math.random()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) method.

So instead of:

```
Math.floor(Math.random *( colors.length));
```

use

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
```